# Getting current URL from Android WebView

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-webview, google-street-view

I just want to obtain the **current URL** with the coordinates of the Google Street View on Android WebView browser.

The scenariou is simple, I am loading the page like this
`webView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/maps/@48.57,19.12")`,
it opens the Google Street View, I do some clicks to move on a street and then `webView.getUrl()` always returns the starting original URL, but meanwhile URL had changed which I clearly see on PC browser URL.

The problem is that the clicks on a street doesn't reload the page, but the same is happening on a Windows and the URL changed there. I tried to override this method shouldOverrideUrlLoading, or using javascript "window.location.href", nothing helps, I always get the first original URL.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Edit:
in onCreate method I put
`webView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());`

And after in MainActivity.class

```
    private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        System.out.println("URL :: " + url);
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
    }
}
```

I tried this version as well, nothing works

```
 public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)
```

Comment: `I tried to override this method shouldOverrideUrlLoading` - can you post your code of what  you tried.

Comment: @Nitish I add the details

Comment: Have you tried enable JS? In kotlin it's `webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true` somewhere in WebView init?

Comment: yes, of course, as I wrote I tried to get url using javascript and it returns always the same initial URL